# Can i track the email is sent or not in c#?

Tags: c#, email, send

I'm using SMTP to send the email, if the receiver email address is wrong then the email is not sent and no exception found.

So anyone helps me to find out the email was sent or not.?

Comment: Just because an e-mail message was sent successfully doesn't mean it will be received successfully - your local SMTP client only reports success if the *first* SMTP hop reports success. Many e-mail systems do not inform the sender if a recipient address exists or not to prevent e-mail address harvesters from culling their mailing-lists, for example.

Comment: As long as your SMTP server accepts the email - no you can't track it.

Comment: You may use https://www.mailgun.com/ or https://sendgrid.com/ as your email sender. They have comprehensive report of your email deliveries.